# How to use match after join in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to filter nested properties after lookup in mongodb. I cannot find proper example in documentation. I use aggregation and in the last stage I have to pass few conditions. I want to filter by properties tightened in lookup stage.

This is my query:

```
        db.collection('leagues').aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {
                            _id: ObjectID(leagueId)
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "league_configs",
                            localField: "_id",
                            foreignField: "leagueId",
                            as: "configs"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "events",
                            localField: "_id",
                            foreignField: "leagueId",
                            as: "events"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $and: [{
                                "events": {
                                    "isCalculated": {
                                        $eq: false
                                    },
                                    "isDeleted": {
                                        $eq: false
                                    },
                                    "startDate": {
                                        $lte: new Date()
                                    }
                                },
                            }]
                        }
                    }
            ])
```

Example league object:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57c6bf5934db7e18b8af650c"),
"name" : "League1",
"adminId" : ObjectId("57c5a08b8857ad1da099e8de"),
"isStarted" : false,
"isFinished" : false,
"users" : [ 
    ObjectId("57c5a08b8857ad1da099e8de")
],
"isPublic" : true,
"createdDate" : "2016-08-31T13:28:25+02:00",
"updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T12:28:09.064Z"),
"currentStage" : 1,
"isDeleted" : false
}
```

Example event object:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57c6bfca34db7e18b8af650f"),
"home" : "home",
"guest" : "guest",
"description" : null,
"result" : "X",
"resultHome" : 1,
"resultGuest" : 1,
"startDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
"type" : "1",
"specialPoints" : null,
"leagueStage" : 1,
"isDeleted" : false,
"isCalculated" : false,
"leagueId" : ObjectId("57c6bf5934db7e18b8af650c"),
"updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-09-02T06:52:45.544Z")
}
```

Any advices?

Comment: Could you please add a sample document of leagues and league_configs collection?

Comment: Okay, in a minute. But do you mean league and events, yep? Why league_configs?

Comment: Yes, events collection. Please specify the nested attribute you would like to refer from that collection as an example?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query. You can use **"$elemMatch"** to filter the data from **"events" collection**. Also, I have renamed the lookup result as "events_docs" rather than "event" for clarity.

Please note that I have removed the first lookup on "league_configs" as I don't have that collection data. You can add that back and try the full query.

The below query work fine with the data you have provided.

**Query:-**

```
db.leagues.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {
                            _id: ObjectId("57c6bf5934db7e18b8af650c")
                        }
                    },
                       {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "events",
                            localField: "_id",
                            foreignField: "leagueId",
                            as: "events_docs"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $match: { "events_docs": {$elemMatch: {"isDeleted" : false,"isCalculated" : false, "startDate": {
                                        $lte: new Date()
                                    }}  } }

                    }

            ]);
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c6bf5934db7e18b8af650c"),
    "name" : "League1",
    "adminId" : ObjectId("57c5a08b8857ad1da099e8de"),
    "isStarted" : false,
    "isFinished" : false,
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("57c5a08b8857ad1da099e8de")
    ],
    "isPublic" : true,
    "createdDate" : "2016-08-31T13:28:25+02:00",
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T12:28:09.064Z"),
    "currentStage" : 1,
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "events_docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c6bfca34db7e18b8af650f"),
            "home" : "home",
            "guest" : "guest",
            "description" : null,
            "result" : "X",
            "resultHome" : 1,
            "resultGuest" : 1,
            "startDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "type" : "1",
            "specialPoints" : null,
            "leagueStage" : 1,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "isCalculated" : false,
            "leagueId" : ObjectId("57c6bf5934db7e18b8af650c"),
            "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-09-02T06:52:45.544Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

**Test Case 2:-**
I ran the same query for league id = ObjectId("57ce74076eae72aafab03013"). The query fetched zero documents.

**League Document:-**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ce74076eae72aafab03013"),
    "name" : "League1",
    "adminId" : ObjectId("57c5a08b8857ad1da099e8de"),
    "isStarted" : false,
    "isFinished" : false,
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("57c5a08b8857ad1da099e8de")
    ],
    "isPublic" : true,
    "createdDate" : "2016-08-31T13:28:25+02:00",
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T12:28:09.064Z"),
    "currentStage" : 1,
    "isDeleted" : false
}
```

**Events Documents:-**

This event doesn't have any league id.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ce74256eae72aafab03014"),
    "home" : "home",
    "guest" : "guest",
    "description" : null,
    "result" : "X",
    "resultHome" : 1,
    "resultGuest" : 1,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "type" : "1",
    "specialPoints" : null,
    "leagueStage" : 1,
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "isCalculated" : false,
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-09-02T06:52:45.544Z")
}
```

This event has league id (ObjectId("57ce74076eae72aafab03013")), however the isDeleted and isCalculated attributes are set to true. So, the query didn't fetch this document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ce74ea6eae72aafab03015"),
    "home" : "home",
    "guest" : "guest",
    "description" : null,
    "result" : "X",
    "resultHome" : 1,
    "resultGuest" : 1,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "type" : "1",
    "specialPoints" : null,
    "leagueStage" : 1,
    "isDeleted" : true,
    "isCalculated" : true,
    "leagueId" : ObjectId("57ce74076eae72aafab03013"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-09-02T06:52:45.544Z")
}
```

Comment: That seem to not working fine. Your query just ignore $elemMatch conditions, always returning whole collection of events with proper leagueId. I had an exactly the same problem with my former query. Could you please test your query with documents which not fulfill conditions?

Comment: I have changed the flag value and tested it. It worked fine I.e. didn't bring any results.

Comment: Here we have a response. Query returns event with isDeleted set on true. https://postimg.org/image/6bcn1t5v3/

Comment: If you run my query, it would show the events attributes in array (not as a flat high level attribute as present in the screenshot). I think you have modified my query for your requirement which may be causing some problem. I think I have added enough evidence that the query works fine.

Comment: That's your query. Only presentation level decided to show them as high level attribute.